# PyQt5 ошибка пропущенного аргумента

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Хочу подключить python файл, сгенерированный из ui-файла интерфейса, созданного через `Qt Designer`, но выходит ошибка:

> TypeError: setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Dialog'

Вот код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import PyQt5.QtGui
import sys
import menu


class startos():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("start __init__")
        self.ui = menu.Ui_Dialog
        self.ui.setupUi(window)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    objOs = startos()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ui_Dialog` не инициализирован, должно быть:

```
self.ui = menu.Ui_Dialog()
```